# Is long polling more resource efficient than classical polling?

Tags: comet, polling, tornado, long-polling

Why is it more efficient for me to hold an http connection open until content comes and then re-open the connection than to simply open a connection periodically?

Ofcourse the latter scenario is perhaps more hit or miss but I am asking purely from a resource efficiency point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By keeping a connection open, you are blocking resources but not incurring the overhead of periodic tearing down connections and setting up connections. Setting & closing a socket connection is lot more expensive underneath the function call. Sending the close intent to the connection end point, freeing the kernel resources and memory associated with it. For opening the connection, the same in reverse happens. For allocating kernel resources, there may be serialized calls (depends on kernel implementation) which can affect the overall system performance. Last but not the least, the hit-n-miss approach is not a deterministic model.

Comment: +1 repeated tearing down and setting up is likely biggest cost

Comment: Thanks! I figured this but wasn't sure and also figured it would be nice to hear it from someone knowledgeable...

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a thread blocked on a socket waiting for a response.  (As in comet).  During that time, the thread isn't scheduled by the kernel and other things on the machine can run.  However if you're polling the thread is busy with brief wait periods.  This also adds latency because you won't know of a need to do something until the poll occurs.

Comment: Are you saying that memory is also freed up while the connection is held open and nothing is being sent to the client?...

Comment: most of the time the connection is held open and waiting for a response from the server.  "nothing is going on" for the most part.  (actually to be more precise  however resources (ex. memory, kernel handles) are tied up during this time.